# ionic 5 page transition url changes but previous page still visible

Tags: angularjs, routes, ionic4

I'm building an Ionic 5 app, but am having a problem getting the pages to transition properly.

The url is changing, but the new page is overlaying the old page, instead of replacing it.

One way I've tried is:

```
<div id="back" class="top-left-nav-area circle">
  <img [routerLink]="['/onboard']" src="./assets/imgs/login/rightarrow.svg" class="rightarrow" alt="" />
</div>
```

Another way is:

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

...

constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
) {}

...

this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/forgotpassword');
```

Neither way works, as they both result in the new page overlaying the old page.

I must be missing something, but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Didn't you find any errors on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `navigateRoot` method instead.

> Going **root** means that all existing pages in the stack will be removed, and the navigated page will become the single page in the stack.

**Component**

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
...
constructor(private navController: NavController) {}
...
this.navController.navigateRoot('/yourLink');
```

**Template**

```
<ion-button routerLink="/yourLink" routerDirection="root">Button</ion-button>
```

Comment: How can I do that using [routerLink] in the html?

Comment: Also, there must be a way to get navigateForward to work properly, because you shouldn't have to clear the stack on every navigation to get the transition to work properly, should you?

Comment: @AlphaBeta I have updated my answer with an example for the template. Not really. In order to achieve animations between pages when going forward and backward, Ionic pushes every new page on top of the stack. That way, you can go back to the previous page using a smooth animation, without having to reload it. This is the expected behavior. Think of an iOS app with a NavigationController, it works the same way.

Comment: So if I use routerDirection="forward", would it perform the page transition and add the new page to the stack, instead of replacing the stack with the new page? The problem I'm getting is that the page transition is not happening, so both the old and new page are visible and merged together. That's the bit I need to solve.

Comment: Also, for some reason I haven't been able to fathom yet, using navigateForward in the code changes the url, but no page transition happens, not even any merging of the pages. Any suggestions why would be gratefully received too.

Comment: @AlphaBeta `forward` is the default value for the routerDirection, no need to explicitly define it. The animation not happening when transitioning to a new page might be caused by a bug in the latest Ionic versions (unstable release) or by and incompatible yet Angular version. Could you post the output of `ionic info` while being at the root of your project ? Also, does the issue occur with a specific page, or with all pages whatsoever ? Could you provide a repository that reproduce this issue so I can investigate on my own ?